# Swift: Creating an NSXMLNode

Tags: xml, swift, nsxmlnode

I'm trying to create an NSXMLNode using Swift. This seems like it should be pretty straightforward based on [the class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLNode_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSXMLNode/attributeWithName:stringValue:) (and Xcode's autocompletion):

```
var anAttribute: NSXMLNode = NSXMLNode.attributeWithName("name", stringValue: "string")
```

But I get an error: "Missing argument for parameter 'URI' in call."

I then try:

```
var anAttribute: NSXMLNode = NSXMLNode.attributeWithName("name", URI: "uri", stringValue: "string")
```

Which produces the equally beguiling error: "Extra argument 'URI' in call."

Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`attributeWithName()` returns `AnyObject?`, the Swift mapping of `id`. Therefore you
have to cast the return value to the expected type:

```
let anAttribute = NSXMLNode.attributeWithName("name", stringValue: "string") as NSXMLNode
```

or, if you want to check for a possible failure:

```
if let anAttribute = NSXMLNode.attributeWithName("name", stringValue: "string") as? NSXMLNode {
    // success
} else {
    // failed
}
```

---

The underlying reason is that the Objective-C function

```
+ (id)attributeWithName:(NSString *)name stringValue:(NSString *)value
```

returns `id`. If it were declared as

```
+ (instancetype)attributeWithName:(NSString *)name stringValue:(NSString *)value
```

(which is the "modern" way to declare class/factory methods) then this would be
mapped to Swift as

```
 class func attributeWithName(_ name: String!,
             stringValue value: String!) -> NSXMLNode!
```

making the explicit cast unnecessary.
You could file a bug report to Apple about that.